# É recomendável usar o Linq em vez de SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Para evitar abuso de string e evitar problemas de injeção de código pode ser uma boa pratica o uso do *Linq*.

Também posso imaginar que por exemplo, que seja mais devagar.

Quem já usou o *Linq* para comunicar com banco de dados, o recomendaria?

Comment: Em que **contexto**?

Comment: Eu estou no processo de ser aceito ou não num novo emprego, onde usam o C# e ligam com banco de dados (no caso por GUI local, não por web). Eu não tenho experiência extensa com o C# e daí fico curioso se a prática comum seria usar Linq ou usar SQL por string, e se isso é uma boa ou má prática... Vendo a sua pergunta posso entender que isso depende do contexto?

Comment: **Sim!** É importantíssimo um contexto para que sua pergunta seja respondida. Postei uma resposta, mas no final das contas note que não respondi diretamente sua pergunta, apenas discorri sobre o assunto. Já com um contexto seria possível afirmar *"isto é/não é recomendável"*.

Comment: Mesmo assim, a sua resposta na verdade é mesmo o que precisei ouvir! Obrigado!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397926.aspx) em si é uma parte do .NET que adiciona ao framework funcionalidades de consulta. Linq não é atrelado a nenhuma tecnologia, ele trabalha sobre uma interface ([IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb546158.aspx)). A implementação da consulta final (que acessa o provedor de dados) fica a cargo de quem implementa a interface.

Se você está utilizando linq para acessar um banco de dados SQL é porque está usando alguma implementação específica para isso (como [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/data/ef.aspx), [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386976.aspx) ou [NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/)).

Em termos de segurança de código não dá para afirmar... nada. Isso fica dependente da implementação do *provider* que você estiver utilizando.

O que é possível afirmar é que uma das vantagens de se utilizar linq é que suas queries serão compiladas, isto é, dependendo do que for erroneamente alterado o compilador poderá te gerar um erro.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que é removida uma coluna do banco de dados. Analogamente a remoção da coluna você altera também o código do sistema para sua classe e suas *queries* não referenciarem a coluna. Se por ventura o programador esquece de substituir em uma consulta que utiliza linq o compilador irá gerar um erro de compilação, pois as *queries* envolverão uma propriedade que não existe mais. Já com *queries* sql como texto isso não acontece, irá ocorrer somente o erro em execução.

Uma possível vantagem de se utilizar *queries* sql diretamente é performance. Geralmente, por oferecerem um nível maior de abstração, as consultas feitas indiretamente com linq tendem a não ser tão performáticas quanto executar uma consulta sql diretamente. Existem alguns casos que essa pequena diferença de performance é relevante. É comum encontrar sistemas que fazem apenas as operações mais pesadas dessa forma.

Comment: Obrigado, deixa bem claro que algumas supostas vantagens não necessariamente estão aí. Daí sei em quê preciso prestar atenção.

Comment: E é sempre bom lembrar: pelo menos em relação a bancos relacionais, e pelo menos quanto ao LINQ utilizado com Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL e NHibernate, a consulta LINQ *será automaticamente transformada*, no final das contas, em uma consulta SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Embora seu questionamento já esteja respondido, o título de sua pergunta me atraiu a compartilhar alguns **outros benefícios** que temos sentido em nossa empresa no uso do Linq, caso alguém esteja passando pelo mesmo processo de decisão. Então lá vai:

- O `Linq` troca o uso de [Strings Mágicas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_m%C3%A1gicas) por instruções compiladas: Na prática, você traz às suas query's os benefícios de uma [linguagem fortemente tipada](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_tipada) e de [refatoração](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o);
- O `Linq` nos trouxe de quebra uma auto-documentação, pois ao criar as classes tivemos que rever o mapeamento entre as tabelas (como possuímos uma base legada, não utilizávamos `contraints` de chave estrangeira). Deu trabalho, mas hoje novos programadores conseguem facilmente navegar de uma tabela a outra sem se preocupar com `joins`. Ainda, a mão na roda do `Intellisense` do Visual Studio torna a escrita de query's muito rápida;
- O `Linq` padroniza todas as query's criadas no mundo .NET. No caso de Linq para SQL, isso significa que você adotará um mesmo padrão podendo este ser renderizado em vários dialetos* de bancos de dados distintos. Vale lembrar que ainda que o SQL seja uma [linguagem ANSI](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), é difícil se restringir ao padrão (tome as funções SQL `substring` e `top N` como exemplo);
- E se você ainda precisar de uso de String's para formar sua query dinamicamente sem muita complicação, você pode recorrer ao [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).

E sim, volta e meia temos problemas de performance por query's mal formadas, mas dá-se um jeito. Em resumo, digo que vale (muito) à pena.

[*] Em nosso caso, estamos utilizando o Linq para SQL implementado pelo excelente [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) que já traz [suporte aos bancos de dados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7247289/666104) mais comuns do mercado.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, o uso do LINQ força o programador a proteger seu código contra injeção de SQL.

Sim, o LINQ algumas vezes é mais lento. Mas há mais de uma maneira de detectar e resolver estes problemas.

Sim, já usei o LINQ extensivamente para comunicar com banco de dados e recomendo. Principalmente na versão para Entity Framework, já que o Linq-to-SQL não é mais atualizado.

Answer (score 4):

Nas minhas experiências, o `LINQ` tem várias qualidades, sim, mas tem suas limitações também. Já passei, por exemplo, de um Dataset tão grande que o `LINQ` quebrou todo o programa. Usando um `for { ... }`, consegue fazer a mesma coisa mas extremamente mais rápido.

Creio que essa lentidão vem do extremo 'overhead' que usando o `LINQ` traz, sendo que no fundo, o .NET faz um `for { ... }` do mesmo jeito.

(Desculpe o português aí :P)

Comment: Você vai dizer que não viveu no Brasil quase sua vida toda? :D

Comment: Vivi alguns anos no Brasil só :)

Answer (score 0):

O que posso dizer do LINQ, no meu ponto de vista só vale a pena para fazer cadastros, simples. Mesmo assim não vejo vantagem. Veja bem, o Delphi sempre foi uma linguagem de desenvolvimento muito rápido, e faz exatamente  o que o link faz, estranho eu estar falando isso mais veja bem, quando você usa os componente do Delphi como o ClientDataSet, ele vai fazer um mapeamento da sua tabela e ali ele adiciona todas as funcionalidades básicas de um cadastro, o problema é que ele faz um mapeamento da tabela de acordo com o banco de dados que você está utilizando e desta forma ele te amarra no banco, se você precisar mudar de banco você teria problemas, vários. No Linq acontece este mesmo mapeamento da tabela, ele acaba criando as classes mais também vai amarra o banco que você esta utilizando, sendo que quando você usa SQL, você faz a criação de cada classe separadamente, usando os tipos de campos primitivos que vai servir para qualquer banco de dados, basicamente você tem a conexão ao banco e as classes que representa as suas tabelas, não tem um vinculo direto, então no final, vai ser SQL puro fora que não vai precisar aprender uma nova sintaxe do LINQ. Então para mim no meu ponto de vista não compensa, eu desenvolvo usando um projeto para o Repositorio, Dominio, Aplicação e um projeto para a apresentação, acho que vale a pena você fazer um pequeno projeto, para testar mais para mim  o LINQ, só é bom para fazer cadastro simples.  Sobre a Injeção de SQL, basta usar o @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  no HTML e na controller [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].